# What is the proper etiquette when greeting/meeting a Venerable?

Tags: lay-practices

Am completely new to the practice. What is the custom/proper etiquette when meeting a Venerable, in this instance for the first time but still applies overall? Further, is one to bow to the Buddha first and then greet? Please be as detailed and specific as possible. Example, If one is to bow, how and how many times, when, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
You bow one time when you meet the monk and you bow one time when you depart. You bow to the Buddha statue when you offer flowers, incense sticks, oil lamps etc. or when you chant some verse in front of the statue.

Answer (score 1):

There's a YouTube video [here](https://youtu.be/7Vhm1sHiIRw), by Ven. Yuttadhammo, entitled "[Monk Radio: Greeting a Monk](https://youtu.be/7Vhm1sHiIRw)".

Comment: Answer provided around 3:00 is very descript.

Answer (score -1):

Is this really mandatory? I haven't met a "venerable" until now. These days one has to be very careful, because there are monks who teach wrong things. Also sticking to useless rites is Silabbatupadana. If you bow down that's fine - I wouldn't. I associate bowing down with submissiveness, but that's just me. If it helps the mind, it helps. Just be cautious of idiolizating the monk and also question everything as stated in the Kalama Sutta.